# Indexing with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an unbalanced panel by country as the following:

```
cname    year  disability_PC  family_PC ... allFunctions_PC
Denmark  1992    953.42         1143.25 ...   9672.43
Denmark  1995    1167.33        1361.62 ...   11002.45
Denmark  2000    1341           1470.54 ...   11200
Finland  1991    1095           955     ...   7164
Finland  1996    1067           1040    ...   7600
```

And so on for more years and countries. What I would like to do is to compute the mobile indexing for each of the type of social expenditures (disability_PC, family_PC, ... allFunctions_PC).

Therefore, I tried the following:

```
pdata %>% 
group_by(cname) %>% 
mutate_at(vars(disability_absPC, family_absPC, Health_absPC, oldage_absPC, unemp_absPC, housing_absPC, allFunctions_absPC),
 funs(chg = ((./lag(.))*100)))
```

The code seems to work, as R reports the first 10 columns and correctly says "with 56 more rows, and 13 more variables". However, these are not added to the data frame. I mean, typing

```
view(pdata)
```

the variables are not existing, as if the mutate command did not create these variables. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for the support.

Comment: The values are there, just do `as.data.frame`.  It is from the printing options from `tibble`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make this simpler with some of the `select_helpers` and also the `funs` is deprecated.  In place, we can use the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
pdata <- pdata %>% 
           group_by(cname) %>% 
           mutate_at(vars(ends_with('absPC')), list(chg = ~ ((./lag(.))*100))
```

---

Regarding the issue of not creating the variables, based on the OP's code, the output is not assigned to any object identifier or updated the original object (`<-`).  If it is done, the columns will be created

Comment: That's perfect with the "ends_with", thank you! (yes, my bad in missing the identifier)